# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>

Tags: reactjs

I get below error and my rows are not rendered. What am I doing wrong?

```
> index.js:2178 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot
> appear as a child of <tbody>.
>     in tbody (at VendorsPage.js:39)
>     in table (at VendorsPage.js:31)
>     in div (at VendorsPage.js:30)
>     in div (at VendorsPage.js:28)
>     in VendorsPage (created by Connect(VendorsPage))
>     in Connect(VendorsPage) (created by Route)
>     in Route (at App.js:27)
>     in div (at App.js:22)
>     in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>     in BrowserRouter (at App.js:21)
>     in div (at App.js:20)
>     in App (created by Connect(App))
>     in Connect(App) (at index.js:15)
>     in Provider (at index.js:14)
```

VendorsPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchVendors } from '../actions/index';

class VendorsPage extends Component {
  renderTable() {
    const vendors = this.props.vendors;
    if (vendors) {
      vendors.map((vendor, index) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(vendor));
        return (
          <tr key={vendor._id}>
            <td>{index}</td>
            <td>{vendor.code}</td>
            <td>{vendor.name}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchVendors());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Vendors</h1>
        <div>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.renderTable()}
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ vendors }) {
  return { vendors };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(VendorsPage);
```

The console.log() in the renderTable() does print my vendors correctly. I tried removing spaces like some other threads suggested, but that is not the problem. All it prints is below

[Vendors Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC3bC.png)

Please help..

Comment: You have an extra `}`

Comment: Duhh.. Thanks kalley

Answer (score -1):

there is an extra `}` in your code
it should be

```
<tbody>
{this.renderTable()} 

</tbody>
```